# AmChart line chart keeps on expanding on value Axis

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm building a line chart and I use Chrome dev tool to debug it like in the picture below.

[image]

For some reason when I click on next so that the debugger continues execution the chart expands downwards continuously extending the value axis like in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your full makechart code and a sample markup that reproduces this as well in the form of a fiddle? I suspect your markup has something to do with it.

Comment: yes, you are right, it seems that the container of the chart needs to have height and width attributes defined.  thanks @xorspark

Comment: That's correct, it needs a width and height. Note that this can also happen if you have the chart inside a table. In this case, you also need to set `table-layout: fixed` in the table's CSS to prevent it from auto-expanding inside a table cell.